# Как остановить выполнение функции при наведении на элемент?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как остановить выполнение функции при наведении на элемент?
Добавил чтобы останавливался setInterval, но как сделать чтобы останавливалось первое выполнение функции при наведении на элемент?

```
function swapImages() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.zz_a').addClass('map-show');
                    $('.t_a').addClass('map-show');
                    $('.a_a').addClass('map-show');
                }, 500);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.zz_a').removeClass('map-show');
                    $('.t_a').removeClass('map-show');
                    $('.a_a').removeClass('map-show');
                }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
            swapImages();
            intervalId  = setInterval(function(){
                swapImages()},1000);
            });

        $('#super-map').hover(function () {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        });
```

Comment: что значит "останавливалось первое выполнение функции" ?

Comment: прервать выполнение функции swapImages при наведении на элемент #super-map

Comment: а сейчас что не так?

Comment: а сейчас в моем коде останавливается setInterval, функция если запущена, она продолжает выполнятся, мне нужно чтобы прерывалось выполнение функции

Answer (score 0):

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
let freeze = false;

function myFunction() {
  if (freeze) return;
    
  console.log('do something');
}

box.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  freeze = true;
});

box.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  freeze = false;
});

setInterval(() => {
  myFunction();
}, 1000);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 213, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">freeze</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```js
let freeze = false;

function swapImages() {
  console.log('swapImages:do something #0');
  
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (freeze) return;
    console.log('swapImage.setTimeout:do something #1');
    $('.zz_a').addClass('map-show');
    $('.t_a').addClass('map-show');
    $('.a_a').addClass('map-show');
  }, 500);
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (freeze) return;
    console.log('swapImage.setTimeout:do something #2');
    $('.zz_a').removeClass('map-show');
    $('.t_a').removeClass('map-show');
    $('.a_a').removeClass('map-show');
  }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  swapImages();
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
      swapImages()
  }, 1000);

  $('.box').hover(function() {
    freeze = true;
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 213, 255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">freeze</div>
```

Comment: можно на примере моего кода? сейчас в моем коде останавливается setInterval, функция если запущена, она продолжает выполнятся, мне нужно чтобы прерывалось выполнение функции

Comment: @ВасяХароший, у Вас выполнение функции и так прерывается.

Comment: @ВасяХароший, обновил.

Comment: @meine мне кажется корректнее было бы прерывать все таймауты, а не заставлять их бегать постоянно, но ничего не делая

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, полностью с Вами согласен.